# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInWithCredential on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I got this problem at sign in function with firebase, I don't know how to solve it. Please help, thanks.

the code of my sign in function is like:

```
Future<void> signIn() async{
final formState = _formKey.currentState;
if(formState.validate()){
  //TODO login to firebase
  formState.save();
  try{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Home(user: user)));
  }catch(e){
    print(e.details);
  }

}
```

}

and my flutter doctor is like:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.4.20-pre.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale
zh-Hans-CN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.3)
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1.8)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

the output of the error is like:

```
 [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 
    MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method  signInWithCredential on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:300:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
1      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:278:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
2      FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:249:12)
3      _LoginPageState.signIn (package:pdc/Pages/Setup/signIn.dart:62:57)
<asynchronous suspension>
4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
8      TapGestureR<…>
```

It happens both on my device and IOS simulator, and I didn't try it on android.
I have already tried the flutter clean, start a new project, and upgrade the cocoaPods. But none of them is useful to my case.
Thanks for help.

## update question

It seems that whenever I try to do something with firebase, it will come up to this kind of question.
I wrote code to sign up like this:

```
Future<void> signUp() async{
        if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Home(user: user)));
    }

  }
```

The output of my code is

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:300:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:108:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _LoginPageState.signUp (package:pdc/Pages/Setup/signIn.dart:78:55)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:177:9)
#8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:436:9)
```

And I'm sure I finished the setup of firebase and successfully connected flutter app with firebase.

Comment: the solution in my case is: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a really hard time in making Firebase work. I think it should be REALLY easy, as both Flutter and Firebase are Google products. Anyway, I had to  use this code for the `AppDelegate.m` file in iOS:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]; // YES;
}
@end
```

Have you tried something like this already?

Comment: Any suggestions for AppDelegate.swift?

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue and solve it by upgrading firebase_auth package.

Comment: if you day the version of your package will be more helpful.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo Isn't latest?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run packages get & upgrade. 
If you are using Android studio you can just go in your pubspeck.yaml file and two buttons will appear in the top right corner or you can just use your terminal.

[Using packages.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I believed I have tried this solution, and I just run them again, but it didn't work for me, I still got the same error.